# Netconvert consuming all RAM

Tags: sumo

So I bumped into the following problem. For the project I'm working on I'm trying to project Spain within SUMO.

The steps I took to do this was first download the 'spain.osm.pbf' file from https://download.geofabrik.de/ as using openstreetmap is impossible to take such a huge file.

Next I downloaded osmosis and converted to .osm.pbf file to a .osm file. The file become 15gb large.

Lastly I use NETCONVERT to convert it from a .osm to a .net.xml.

Now here lies the problem, using netconvert to convert the file just slowly consumes all my RAM (16gb). And when it reaches the max my screen goes black and my pc basically crashed. Which makes sense.

Is there any step I'm missing or doing wrong to properly convert this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your application you probably do not need all streets. You could try one of the various [filtering options of netconvert](https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/NETCONVERT#Edge_Removal) or skip the generation of junction internal edges using `--no-internal-links` which also take a lot of memory. Also try running netconvert in verbose mode to see at which step it fails. (Using a computer with more RAM will help as well, but you probably guessed that yourself.)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. Am I wrong to think that NETCONVERT will first put the whole .osm file in RAM and then convert it to a .net.xml file and applying any filter options? Meaning that it doesn't really matter when the file exceeds my RAM?

Comment: Meaning that additional filters don't really matter when the file exceeds my RAM?*

Comment: netconvert's representation maybe a bit more efficient than XML but yes you are close to the bounds here. You might want to try osmfilter https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter first to filter for the relevant streets (you should convert to o5m first)

Comment: Hey sorry for the late answer! This is a really useful comment. I can definitely use this to help me out. One last question, is there a good list or way to find out all the parameter options? In the example i can for example see "--keep="highway="" to keep all the "highway". But where would I find other options? Like walkroads, tramways, cycling roads whatever.

Comment: The osm format is always changing but to get an idea of which ways sumo imports, have a look at the typemap: https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Networks/Import/OpenStreetMap#Recommended_Typemaps